# Python Djangocms Install App WSGI vs 8000 port

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I follow the tutorial http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/introduction/plugins.html, when I install the Polls App as indicated it is visible on 8000 port But not in WSGI/Apache mode (error message no module polls). To see the APP polls I need to copy Polls application files in the default root directory. Idem with the Aldryn Blog News. I guess I have to specify some more PATH in wsgi mode  to help Python to find the modules. Where and how to do that in my Virtualenv, to be also effective when I deploy all the stuff on a remote platform ?
Thanks for any help

Thank you for your interest. IMHO I don't think the problem is on APACHE configuration, everything is OK and DjangoCMS works without polls. Herinafter the conf file, the domain is a local virtual one.
  
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/djangocms" 
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/djangocms/default/wsgi.py
    ServerName djangocms.net
    Alias /static/ /var/www/djangocms/default/static/
    
        Options +ExecCGI
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    
    ErrorLog "logs/errordjangocms_log"
    LogLevel error

Marcel

Comment: post your apache config... you are correct its likely missing a path setting.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. IMHO I don't think the problem is on APACHE configuration, everything is OK. Herinafter the conf file, the domain is a local virtual one. <VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/djangocms"
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/djangocms/default/wsgi.py
 ServerName djangocms.net
 Alias /static/ /var/www/djangocms/default/static/
 <Directory /var/www/djangocms/>
  Options +ExecCGI
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from All
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog "logs/errordjangocms_log"
 LogLevel error

</VirtualHost>

Comment: i can't read that well, but think you are missing items. I've added my code that work in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working config i use

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName iot.mydomain.com
ServerAlias iot

WSGIDaemonProcess iot.local python-path=/home/name/PycharmProjects/iotdata
WSGIProcessGroup iot.local
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/name/PycharmProjects/iotdata/iotdata/wsgi.py process-group=iot.local
#WSGIPythonPath /home/name/PycharmProjects/iotdata

Alias /static/ /home/name/PycharmProjects/iotdata/static/

<Directory /home/name/PycharmProjects/iotdata>

<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
<Directory /home/name/PycharmProjects/iotdata/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: #About conf Apache/WSGI
Thanks for your help. Sorry, I was Clumsy with markdowns.

Hereinafter my conf file, no reason to have trouble there. DjangoCms works in mode WSGI without the polls application installed.

```Apache
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/djangocms"
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/djangocms/default/wsgi.py
 ServerName djangocms.net
 Alias /static/ /var/www/djangocms/default/static/
 <Directory /var/www/djangocms/>
  Options +ExecCGI
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from All
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog "logs/errordjangocms_log"
 LogLevel error

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks I give you clearer in last answer, see above.